# Pin code based expected delivery in magento product details page

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, delivery, delivery-date

I am developing a Magento based application for a gold selling company.

Now I got stuck with the requirement for including the **expected delivery** for products **based on pin code**.

I tried some extensions, but all failed. Most of the extensions come with COD availability. But I need the expected delivery date actually.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: you check this https://www.magecomp.com/magento-cod-checker.html

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Here I am using Megento 1.9

Comment: Hi @jigsparmar, I tried this and COD option in backend. But I am not able to see the expected delivery option in that. Please help me to find that out.

Comment: http://www.adsxon.com/xiaomi-redmi-note-3-dark-grey-32gb.html

check your requirment   use 123456 as pin code

Comment: @jigsparmar, http://magecomp.biz/demo2/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/checkout/website/base/key/cc3a976d90f355c997d3e771c59123cd/ is the given admin panel link for demo and there is no provision for entering expected data. And also in http://magecomp.biz/demo2/checkout/cart/, the demo view page, I cannot see the pin code entry area.

Comment: thats why am telling you to check in this url 
 
adsxon.com/xiaomi-redmi-note-3-dark-grey-32gb.html

Comment: Hi @jigsparmar, adsxon.com/xiaomi-redmi-note-3-dark-grey-32gb.html is my real requirment. But which extension is this and how can see the back end of this extension.

Comment: you see scrrenshot in this https://www.magecomp.com/magento-cod-checker.html url and in admin you just upload one csv five nothing else

Comment: http://magecomp.biz/demo2/cod/iphone-5s-5gs.html  it extension of magecomp now all work good.  you check

Comment: hwy @jithin did you check?

Comment: @jigsparmar: Yeah I have checked. But I cannot get the admin area. So finally I tried to develop a new extension for my requirement and it worked.